# ehcache-clustered not working in OSGi when project is installed several times

Tags: osgi, aem, ehcache, terracotta, ehcache-3

Having troubles with clustered ehcache in osgi/aem. Only with first project build/installation it works fine, but with second build/installation it stops working, generate a lot of errors. It looks like terracotta connection, cachemanager or something third is not properly closed.

Even after deleting bundles it tries connect to terracotta.

[ok log](https://pastebin.com/6e2jiee5), [errors in log](https://pastebin.com/UfdrspbG)

I'm installing ehcache and ehcache-clustered as standalone bundles in osgi. Also tried with embedding them into my bundle. Ehcache and ehcache-clustered are set as dependencies, also tried with org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-cache-api (embedding, not sure if it's needed)

First time all ehcache and ehcache-clustered services are active, 2nd time are satisfied.

[Ehcache bundle](https://pastebin.com/sEM6nghG), [ehcache-clustered bundle](https://pastebin.com/VBf1h9ED), [javax-cache-api bundle](https://pastebin.com/KWWR0XXC), [my project bundle](https://pastebin.com/W4vk2mqu)

[pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/CwFQiLES)

Same code I have tired as standalone java app and it works perfectly fine (https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/clustered/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sample/ClusteredXML.java)

So not sure what I have missed (dependencies, import packages..)?

[ehcache config](https://pastebin.com/PxshKNc6), [terracotta config](https://pastebin.com/Rt13ZUES)

```
@Activate
private void activate() {
    LOGGER.info("Creating clustered cache manager from XML");

    URL myUrl = ClusteredService.class.getResource("/com/myco/services/ehcache-clustered-local2.xml");
    Configuration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(myUrl);

    try (CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(xmlConfig) ) {
        cacheManager.init();

        org.ehcache.Cache<String, String> basicCache = cacheManager.getCache("basicCache4", String.class, String.class);

        LOGGER.info("1. Putting to cache");
        basicCache.put("1","abc");

        LOGGER.info("1. Getting from cache");
        String value = basicCache.get("1");
        LOGGER.info("1. Retrieved '{}'", value);

        LOGGER.info("cache manager status2, " + cacheManager.getStatus().toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "second build/installation"? Restarting the bundle or installing a second bundle that also uses ehcache?

Comment: I mean when I install new version of my bundle where I actually use ehcache. So for example, working in local environment, there is no ehcache, ehcache-clustered and my-project bundle, with first installation all of theme works fine. Then I do some code changes (not related to ehcache) and install my-project bundle again, than ehcache stops working

Comment: If I extract this code in some method and call it 2 times the same things happens. First time is ok, after it not

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to also create a @Deactivate method where you do a cacheManager.shutdown();

I guess if you call your code in a non OSGi project twice you would also experience the same error.

Comment: It's the same, but cacheManager is closed in try with resources cause it implements closeable. There is no shutdown method, just close(). I had before in activate method just to init cacheManager in deactivate method to close it, and some method to try put and get from cache. If I had call more then once it started generate errors.

Comment: Thanks .. did not see this .. hmm .. then I am out of good ideas.